# Evaluate $\int_{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2,\ x^2+y^2=4}\ (3x-4x^2y)dx+(4x^2y+2y)dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Let $C$ be the circle with centre at origin of radius $2$. Calculate line integral:
$$\int_C(3x-4x^2y)dx+(4x^2y+2y)dy$$

I think the value is $32\pi$. But, the answer key given gives the value as $16\pi$.

Am I wrong somewhere?

I used the Green's theorem to evaluate the integral.

Any hints as to where the mistake lies? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: My result was $32\pi/3$...

Comment: @jobe edited the question, also how did you get $3$ in denominator?

Comment: When integrating $r^2$ over $r$.

Comment: @jobe Oh! I think you used polar coordinates. Note that while transforming to polar, the jacobian is $r$

Comment: Sure! I am going to compute again.

Comment: Now is $16\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Green's theorem
$$
\oint_C(3x−4x^2y)dx+(4x^2y+2y)dy=\int_S(8xy+4x^2)dxdy=\int_S(8r^2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+4r^2\cos^2(\theta))rd\theta,
$$
where polar coordinates were used and $S$ denotes the disc with radius 2. Computing the last integral we have
$$
\int_S(8r^3\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+4r^3\cos^2(\theta))d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}
\Big(32\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+16\cos^2(\theta)\Big{)}d\theta=16\pi.
$$

Comment: thanks for the effort. But, now I just saw the question was misread by me and the answer key is right!